# Split string in half across 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking to write a code that splits a string in half. For example, if the name entered is "Trishy", 6 letters, first 3 letters go into the the second `li` of `<ul class="hardcover_front">` and the latter 3 letters go into the first `li` of `<ul class="hardcover_back">`.

Note that I need this to apply for multiple names of varying character lengths.

```
<div id="book1" class="book">
        <ul class="hardcover_front">
            <li></li>
            <li>Tri</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="hardcover_back">
            <li>shy</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="book_spine">
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Comment: @adiga how would you substring into halves?

Comment: @evilgenious448 did you go through the link i sent? It's straight forward. `substring(0, string_length / 2). Then substring(string_length / 2, string_length). Add some logic to handle the odd string length. The downvotes are a result of you not willing to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "Trishy";

var half = Math.round(s.length / 2);
var first = s.substr(0, half);
var last = s.substr(half + 1, s.length);
$('#book1 ul.hardcover_front').find('li:nth-child(2)').html(first);
$('#book1 ul.hardcover_back').find('li:nth-child(1)').html(last);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This is correct with the exception of the `(half + 1,` should just be `(half,`

Answer (score 4):

Here are some steps to get you going. Use Google to learn about the parts you don't understand. Once you have a semi-working solution just update the question with your JS and see what happens...

- Get the length of the string;
- Determine the middle, take into account that the middle for 7 chars is 3.5 so you will have to use Math to round the result;
- Use `substring` to get the characters you need;
- use `document.querySelector` or similar method to retrieve the element you need from the DOM
- Set the text of the element you've retrieved via `textContent` or `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two halves of the string like this and use them wherever you want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Helloworld!";
    var length = str.length;
   
    if(length%2 == 0){
    res = str.substring(0, length/2);
    res1 = str.substring(length/2, length);
    
    }
    else{
    res = str.substring(0, (length/2) + 1);
    res1 = str.substring((length/2) + 1, length);
    
    }
    alert("First Half- "+res+"\n"+"Second Half- "+res1);
    console.log("First Half- "+res+"\n"+"Second Half- "+res1);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```